# What is wrong with this isSubsetOf-Method?

Tags: java, intervals, calc

I wrote this method for my Interval class with has 2 int-attributes. One for the lower Bound and one for the upper Bound. With this method i want to compare the given Interval other to the already existing Interval this and see, if other is a part or the whole Interval of this.

```
class Interval {
    int lowerBound;
    int upperBound;
    Interval(int lowerBound, int upperBound){
        this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
        this.upperBound = upperBound;
    }

    /**
     * @return Gets the value of lowerBound and returns lowerBound.
     */
    public int getLowerBound() {
        return lowerBound;
    }

    /**
     * @return Gets the value of upperBound and returns upperBound.
     */
    public int getUpperBound() {
        return upperBound;
    }

boolean isSubsetOf(Interval other){
    return this.lowerBound - other.getLowerBound() <= 0 && this.upperBound - other.getUpperBound() >= 0;
}
```

I handed in this solution but got told that the calculation is wrong and I don't get where my mistake is.

Comment: Why use arithmetic? Perhaps it should be `return this.lowerBound >= other.lowerBound && this.upperBound <= other.upperBound;` You could write some *tests* to validate that it behaves as you expect. Then you would know if it is correct (or how it is not).

Comment: you should have a main method to do some boundary testing and show the code and output.

Comment: When invoking, it will be `A.isSubsetOf(B)`. You would want to make it behave exactly as it naturally sounds. For Interval A to be a subset of Interval B, `A.lowerBound >= B.lowerBound` and `A.upperBound <= B.upperBound`. Remove the equals if you want a strict subset.

Comment: Your approach of checking the difference of two int values to be greater than, equal to, or less than 0 instead of comparing the two values directly is error-prone because of the possibility of integer overflow. E.g. compare the results of `Integer.MIN_VALUE < 10` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 10 < 0`.